# Insert a string into a sorted linked list of strings in C

Tags: c, sorting, c-strings, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm struggling with this problem: I want to insert a string into a sorted linked list of strings but for some reason it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
void insert(node** head, const char* word){

  node* newElem = malloc(sizeof(node));
  newElem->data = malloc(sizeof (char)*(wordLenght+1));
  strcpy(newElem->data, word);

  if (*head == NULL || strcmp(newElem->data, (*head)->data) < 0){
      newElem->next = *head;
      *head = newElem;
      return;
  }

  nodo* cursor = *head;
  while (cursor->next != NULL && strcmp(newElem->data, cursor->data) < 0){
      cursor = cursor->next;
  }

  newElem->next = cursor->next;
  cursor->next = newElem;
}
```

I've tried with this set of strings

```
7DJL,-kiF, 8F4r, 7D7d, -D7w, -b7f
```

and it didn't work.
The output should be:

```
-D7w, -b7f, -kiF, 7D7d, 7DJL, 8F4r
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is wordLenght?

Comment: You should be able to step through the code in a debugger to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow its a #define value that defines the word's length

Comment: Shouldn't `nodo *cursor` be `node *cursor`?

Comment: @Barmar yeah I've done it a couple of times, I've also tried to print the result of every confront and all seems to be good

Comment: What are you getting instead of the expected result?

Comment: I think the `while` loop doesn't work when the new element has to be added at the end. It stops when `cursor->next == NULL`.

Comment: @Barmar with these words I got 
-D7w,-kiF,-b7f,7D7d,7DJL,8F4r (the word -kiF is in the wrong place), but if I try with more words the error is way bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what is `wordLenght`. But in any case using this name within the function does not make a sense and only makes the function unclear because the name is not defined within the function.

There is no need to split the function into two parts. It makes the function error-prone.

Moreover the condition of the while statement

```
while (cursor->next != NULL && strcmp(newElem->data, cursor->data) < 0){
```

is incorrect.

If this expression

```
strcmp(newElem->data, cursor->data) < 0
```

evaluates to true you need to interrupt the loop.

Also there is a typo

```
nodo* cursor = *head;
```

It seems you mean

```
node* cursor = *head;
```

The function can look the following way

```
int insert( node** head, const char* word )
{
    node *newElem = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = newElem != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        success = ( newElem->data = malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 ) ) != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            strcpy( newElem->data, word );

            while ( *head != NULL && !( strcmp( word, ( *head )->data ) < 0 ) )
            {
                head = &( *head )->next;
            }

            newElem->next = *head;
            *head = newElem;
        }
        else
        {
            free( newElem );
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int insert( node** head, const char* word )
{
    node *newElem = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = newElem != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        success = ( newElem->data = malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 ) ) != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            strcpy( newElem->data, word );

            while ( *head != NULL && !( strcmp( word, ( *head )->data ) < 0 ) )
            {
                head = &( *head )->next;
            }

            newElem->next = *head;
            *head = newElem;
        }
        else
        {
            free( newElem );
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void display( const node *head )
{
    for ( ; head; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main (void) 
{
    node *head = NULL;
    const char * data[] =
    {
        "7DJL", "-kiF", "8F4r", "7D7d", "-D7w", "-b7f"
    };
    const size_t N = sizeof( data ) / sizeof( *data );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        insert( &head, data[i] );
    }

    display( head );
}
```

The program output is

```
"-D7w" -> "-b7f" -> "-kiF" -> "7D7d" -> "7DJL" -> "8F4r" -> null
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I was looking for, it work with all the other sets of words too

Comment: @SebastianoMora If so then mark the answer as the best answer to close the question.